# Mvvm Cross Navigation throughout fragments

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I cannot bind the click event from layout to ViewModel.

I want to make a navigation throughout two fragments with MVVM Cross 5.6.
I am using native Xamarin.Android.

First, I created a ViewModel:

```cs
public class FirstFragmentViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
   public ICommand NavigateCommand => new MvxCommand(() => { 
     this.ShowViewModel<ProfileFragmentViewModel>(); });
}
```

The used layout is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#005000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate"
        local:MvxBind="Click NavigateCommand"
        android:background="#ffec4747"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, I created a Fragment:

```cs
public class FirstFragmentView : MvxFragment<FirstFragmentViewModel>
{
   public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.FirstFragmentView, null);
   }
}
```

The FirstFragmentView is initailized here:

```cs
[Activity(MainLauncher = true)]
public class TabView : MvxTabsFragmentActivity
{
    public TabView()
        : base(Resource.Layout.Home, Resource.Id.actualtabcontent)
    {
    }

    public FirstFragmentViewModel FirstViewModel => (FirstFragmentViewModel)this.ViewModel;
    public FirstViewModel SecondViewModel => (FirstViewModel)this.ViewModel;

    protected override void AddTabs(Bundle args)
    {
        AddTab<FirstFragmentView>("1", "Tab 1", args, FirstViewModel);
        AddTab<SecondFragmentView>("2", "Tab 2", args, SecondViewModel);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
}
```

The button is displayed but it is in disabled state and clicking it, nothing happens.

Comment: If you take a look at the Output window in visual studio, there are log messages from MvvmCross when something goes wrong, interpreting bindings. And something must be wrong, because your code looks fine

Comment: How is your FirstFragmentView displayed / created ?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Did you have a look at the Output Window's content ?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that was suspicious was that the TabView doesn`t have a ViewModel attached but I do not see a problem in this.

Comment: You might want to add another property, say a String for example, in your Viewmodel, and a TextView to your android layout. Bind that TextView to your Text property and see what happens. If your text does not show up, you have a DataContext issue (meaning that the viewmodel of your tab is not associated with your tab). You may have missed a step in configuring the MvxTabsFragmentActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing in the wrong ViewModel when you call:

```
AddTab<FirstFragmentView>("1", "Tab 1", args, FirstViewModel);
```

The following lines in you Activity look suspicious:

```
public FirstFragmentViewModel FirstViewModel => (FirstFragmentViewModel)this.ViewModel;
public FirstViewModel SecondViewModel => (FirstViewModel)this.ViewModel
```

You are casting `this.ViewModel` to both `FirstFragmentViewModel` and `FirstViewModel`, which doesn't make sense. The Activity and each of the Fragments should have their own separate ViewModels.

Try making this change and see if it works:

```
 AddTab<FirstFragmentView>("1", "Tab 1", args, new FirstFragmentViewModel());
```